# Thread changing heap memory

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gdb

I am compiling this program.

```
char * p;    
void * handler(void * arg)
{
  p = "hello"; // initializing p 
  puts(p);
  puts("------");
  long tid = (long) arg;
  printf("Hello wrold! it is in thread : %ld\n", tid);
  pthread_exit(NULL); //exiting thread 
}

int main() {
  pthread_t t_id[2];
  int rc;
  long t;
  p = malloc(sizeof(100)); // allocating memory tried (p =malloc(sizeof(char)*100);)
  if (p == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  for (t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
    printf("Creating Thread  %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create( & t_id[t], NULL, handler, (void * ) t);
    if (rc) {
      perror("pthread_create");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  pthread_join(t_id[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(t_id[1], NULL);
  free(p); /// segmentation fault here... 
  puts("***");
  //      pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

I am getting segmentation fault here,
I checked using `gdb`.
Surprisingly,Address of `p`  is changing.WHY?

Any helping hand will be appreciated!

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at thread_heap.c:27
27              p=malloc(sizeof(100));
(gdb) p p
*$1 = 0x0*    **/// adress of p**
(gdb) next
28              if(p==NULL)
(gdb) p p      
*$2 = 0x602010 ""*  **// why changed here????**
(gdb) next
35              for (t=0;t<2;t++)
(gdb) p p
$3 = 0x602010 ""
(gdb) next
37                      printf("Creating Thread  %ld\n",t);
(gdb)
Creating Thread  0
38                      rc=pthread_create(&t_id[t],NULL,handler,(void *)t);
(gdb)
[New Thread 0x7ffff77fe700 (LWP 21632)]
.
.
.

114     in pthread_join.c
(gdb)
main () at thread_heap.c:49
49      free(p);
(gdb) p p
*$4 = 0x4009e0 "hello"*   **/// again why changed here?**
(gdb)
$5 = 0x4009e0 "hello"
(gdb) step
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x4009e0) at malloc.c:2959
2959    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) q

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_free (av=0x7ffff7bb6720, p=0x4009d0, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4098
4098    malloc.c: No such file or directory.   // Why this address changed?
(gdb)
```

Comment: `address of p changing` - hmmm, isn't it the value held by `p` that changes? It changes because you assign to `p`

Comment: Non-readonly, non-atomic, unsynchronized access to a shared object from multiple threads -> race-condition, undefined behavior.

Comment: You need to use `strcpy()` to copy strings around.

Comment: `p = malloc(sizeof(100));` random code mutations rarely help in fixing bugs, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in

```
// in main
p = malloc(sizeof(100)); // allocating memory tried (p =malloc(sizeof(char)*100);)

// in handler function
p = "hello"; // initializing p
```

Here `p` is a global variable, and you have previously used malloc on it. In the handler function, you are assigning `p` to the address of a string literal, resulting in a dangling pointer. When you try to free this modified `p` you get an error.

What you should do is

```
const char *hell = "hello";
strcpy(p,hell);
```

Also, fix the malloc to what you had previously. The current code allocates only 4 bytes. (`sizeof (100)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`)

Comment: Thanks you ... Rishikesh...!!

I am not able to understand.... according to thread main process and all thread process shares same heap memory... while switching to main process stack to thread stack , why pointer address is changing??

Could you please elaborate this with some more explaining...

thanks in advance...!!

Comment: @Jaydeep You are passing the function `handler` to `pthread_create` The handler function is changing the pointer.

Comment: Thanks Rishikesh...

But , still why handler is changing pointer , but pointer is globally uninitialized, then it is in BSS section of memory, as per thread concept, Everything is shared except stack...

then how again it is changed??

Comment: @Jaydeep - Exactly, globals are shared. The pointer is  modified first in the main function and then in the handler function. When it comes back to the main function, it gets the new value.

Comment: Still I am not getting...!!

pointer's address or pointer I am not passing like any parameters as well I am not defining any local pointer , then how it is changing!!!!!!!!!!???